# How to get end of week in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

In javascript, well node.js, if I have a `date` object, how can I get the date object of the end of the week, like if the day of the initial object was Wednesday (regardless of time), then how can I get the date object but with it moved 4 days up and to 12:00 am, so Sunday midnight.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and its [endOf()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/)  function

```
    var m = moment(new Date(2011, 2, 12, 5, 0, 0)); 
    m.endOf("week");
```

Comment: Is there a moment.js in node.js?

Comment: you should add it as third-part, look here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/node-js/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var dateObj = new Date();
var day = dateObj.getDay();
var diff = 7 - day;
var neDate = new Date();
neDate.setDate(dateObj.getDate() + diff);
document.getElementById('data').innerText = neDate;
```

```html
<div id='data'></div>
```